# Equivalent to extending HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, error-handling

I got an spring web mvc architecture pice that I do not fully understand.

Java Code:

```
public class ErrorHandler extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en\">");
        out.println("<html><head><title>ERROR</title></head><body>");
        out.println("<h1>An error occured</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>some.package.ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ErrorHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

The semantic of this code is clear, I guess: It is a error handler that catches HTTP status errors on the one hand (403 and 404) but also catches internal exceptions (eg. divide by 0, so internal 500 errors).

Now I whant to refactor it. That means that I want to create mostly java only code because the rest of the project is in this structure as well and I want it to be uniformly.
But here are my problems because from what I researched, it is not compleatly clear to me:

1. Why does someone here extended the `HttpServlet` class? Isn't this the same as a `@RequestMapping` annotation? But when I remove the `extends HttpServlet` and put a `@RequestMapping` to the `doGet` method, what do I have to set for the value? Or is there a mapping at all?
   How can I get rid of the extension?
2. The `<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>` should be equivalent to `@ExceptionHandler(value={Throwable.class})` with a `@RestControllerAdvice`. Or am I wrong here?
3. And what is with the `<error-code>404</error-code>`? Is this equivalent to `@ExceptionHandler(value={ResourceNotFoundException.class})`? Or is it enouph that the Trowable.class is catched?
4. And am I missing something? The new code must be minimum as strong as the old one. So there must be at least the same functionality, but more is ok (ModelAndView as return instead of void and a PrintWriter. And moving the class to other packages without changing the web.xml, ....)

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way your web.xml looks like it doesn't seem to me that this is a Spring MVC application as such is based on `DispatcherServlet` which haven't been included in your deployment descriptor. Nonetheless I've tried to answer your questions.

By extending your class with `HttpServlet` you make that class eligible to manage http requests by overriding methods like `doPost` or `doGet`. Then you can register your servlet inside web.xml and specify mapping for it. It is not equivalent to Spring specific annotation `@RequestMapping`. If you want to handle exceptions with Spring MVC (and therefore don't use `HttpServlet` class for it) you need to configure your web.xml to support Spring MVC, create `@Controller` class and inside it create `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method which will be called whenever given exception has been thrown inside scope of the controller. The other way of handling exceptions in Spring MVC may be a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. If Spring could not have found an exception handler for a thrown exception in the scope of controller in which the exception was thrown it'll look for it in the class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.

If you haven't worked with Spring MVC yet and you're not sure how does it work, check this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/.

Hope I was able to clarify a few things for you.

Comment: the architecture of this project is a total mess. All in All the project has a relatively normal spring mvc architecture. RequestMappings are used together with hibernate and JPA for persistance. But the error handling is "special". And the only thing i am trying to acchieve is, to use a jsp template for the error page. but I can not return a ModelAndView because the methods out of HttpServlet are all void. a `@ExceptionHandler` inside a `@ControllerAdvice` can catch internal 500 errors. But how do I catch 404 and 403 errors? Or is there even a "catch everything"?

Comment: Doesn't your `ErrorHandler` work in case of 404 or 403 errors? Based on your web.xml it should be called whenever those exception are thrown. If you want to use jsp file instead of dealing with `PrintWriter` you can achieve it by: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/examplePage.jsp").forward(request, response);` at the end of your `doGet` method.  You can also pass some additional attributes and display them inside the jsp file, along request by using: `request.setAttribute("data", data);`.

Comment: I now removed everything related to the error handling out of the `web.xml`. I added `<param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>` -> `true` to the dispatcher and have a `@ExceptionHandler` on a spring method. Now internal 500 errors and also 404 are catched. ''BUT'' there is no correct status code in the head. It is always a 200. DO I have to set it manually? If so, how? Or am I missing a configuration?

Comment: You can use `@ResponseStatus` on your `@ExceptionHandler` method to indicate Spring that annotated handler should produce HTTP response with given status code. For example `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` to return 404 status code with response.

Comment: ok, so with a spring based solution I have to provide the status code manually. with the `@ResponseStatus` or inside the method with `response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND  );`. So I now have two solutions: the old one with the web.xml and a new one with the annotations. Is one of them "better"? or does both brovide the EXACT same result? because I can manually configure 403 and 404. but what is with 402 or other, very much rarer errors? do I have to watch out for them in both solutions?

Comment: maybe there are errors, that only the web.xml solution can catch? or is the spring based way as strong as the tomcat config over web.xml?

Comment: The way you want to handle exceptions is your decision but in Spring MVC based application it is rather recommended to use Spring's way but as I said it's your decision. You can always specify the way to handle those less occurring exceptions inside your `@ControllerAdivce` by creating a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)`. This method will catch anything that hasn't been caught inside your specific controller class.